# RUN PHP FORMS using Tab Functionality

Tags: php

I need to create two forms using different jquery tabs in a same page

Requirement :

When I click on "Form1 tab",  I should be able to fill the form and submit data successfully with a message 'success' and also in case any errors, the errors should display within "Form1 tab".

When I click on "Form2 tab",  I should be able to fill the form and submit data successfully with a message 'success' and also in case any errors, the errors should display within "Form2 tab".

But rightnow, for Form1 tab, it works fine and when it comes to Form2 tab, clicking on submit button it redirects to Form1 tab.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #tabs { width:100%; height:30px; border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; padding-right:2px; margin-top:10px; }
      #tabs li { float:left;  list-style:none;  border-top:1px solid #ccc;  border-left:1px solid #ccc;  border-right:1px solid #ccc;  margin-right:5px; 
                 border-top-left-radius:3px; border-top-right-radius:3px; outline:none; }
      #tabs li a { font-family:calibri; font-size:15px; color:#5685bc; padding-top:5px; padding-left:7px; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:8px; 
                   display:block; background: #FFF; border-top-left-radius:3px;  border-top-right-radius:3px; text-decoration:none; outline:none; }
      #tabs li a.inactive { padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:8px; padding-left:8px; padding-right:8px; color:#666666; background:#EEE; outline:none;
                            border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; }
      #tabs li a:hover, #tabs li a.inactive:hover { color:#5685bc; outline:none; }

      .container2 { clear:both; width:99%; border:0px solid #CCC; padding-top:2px; margin:0 auto; }
      .container2 h2 { margin-left:15px;  margin-right:15px;  margin-bottom:10px; color:#5685bc; }
      .container2 p { margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px;  margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; line-height:1.3; font-size:small; }
      .container2 ul { margin-left:25px; font-size:small; line-height:1.4; list-style-type:disc; }
      .container2 li { padding-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px;}
    </style>
    <script src="js/jqueryv1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
      $ (document).ready(function() 
      {    
      $('#tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
      $('.container2').hide();
      $('.container2:first').show();

      $('#tabs li a').click(function()
      {
        var t = $(this).attr('id');
        if($(this).hasClass('inactive'))
        { //this is the start of our condition 
          $('#tabs li a').addClass('inactive');         
          $(this).removeClass('inactive');
          $('.container2').hide();
          $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
        }
      });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
 <body>
    <ul id="tabs">
          <li><a id="tab1">FORM1</a></li>     
          <li><a id="tab2">FORM2 </a></li>        
    </ul>

    <div class="container2" id="tab1C">
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['create_form1']))
        {
           if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
              $errors[] = '<span class="error">All fields are required.</span>';
           }
           else {
              if (isset($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['username'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Username is required</span>'; }          
              if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && empty($_POST['firstname'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Firstname is required</span>'; }
           }
           if (empty($errors) === true) {
               $username = $_POST['username']; 
               $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
               echo $username.'lavanya<br>';
               echo $firstname.'<br>';              
           }
        }
      ?>
      <form method="post">
       <table>
        <tr><td><label>username</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"  size="30">             
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>firstname</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" >           
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit" style="background:#8AC007;color:#080808;padding:6px;" name="create_form1"></td></tr> 
       </table>
      </form>
      <?php          
        if (empty($errors) === false)            
        echo '<div>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</div>';             
      ?>     
    </div>

    <div class="container2" id="tab2C">
     <?php
        if (isset($_POST['create_form2']))
        {      
           $fullname = $_POST['fullname']; 
           $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 

           if (empty($_POST['fullname']) || empty($_POST['lastname'])) {
              $errors[] = '<span class="error">All fields are required.</span>';
           }
           else {
              if (isset($_POST['fullname']) && empty($_POST['fullname'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">fullname is required</span>'; }          
              if (isset($_POST['lastname']) && empty($_POST['lastname'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">lastname is required</span>'; }
           }
           if (empty($errors) === true)   {
              echo $fullname.'<br>';
              echo $lastname.'<br>';              
           }              
        }
      ?>
      <form method="post">
       <table>
        <tr><td><label>fullname</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["fullname"])) echo $fullname; ?>" size="30">               
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>lastname</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname" size="30" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["lastname"])) echo $lastname; ?>">              
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit" style="background:#8AC007;color:#080808;padding:6px;" name="create_form2"></td></tr> 
       </table>
      </form>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ugly way is to check your POST variable and define which tab should be selected. See the modification I made in the `<script>` tag. It's not tested but I hope you get the point. The nice way however would be using AJAX for this but that's a whole other story.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #tabs { width:100%; height:30px; border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; padding-right:2px; margin-top:10px; }
      #tabs li { float:left;  list-style:none;  border-top:1px solid #ccc;  border-left:1px solid #ccc;  border-right:1px solid #ccc;  margin-right:5px; 
                 border-top-left-radius:3px; border-top-right-radius:3px; outline:none; }
      #tabs li a { font-family:calibri; font-size:15px; color:#5685bc; padding-top:5px; padding-left:7px; padding-right:7px; padding-bottom:8px; 
                   display:block; background: #FFF; border-top-left-radius:3px;  border-top-right-radius:3px; text-decoration:none; outline:none; }
      #tabs li a.inactive { padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:8px; padding-left:8px; padding-right:8px; color:#666666; background:#EEE; outline:none;
                            border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; }
      #tabs li a:hover, #tabs li a.inactive:hover { color:#5685bc; outline:none; }

      .container2 { clear:both; width:99%; border:0px solid #CCC; padding-top:2px; margin:0 auto; }
      .container2 h2 { margin-left:15px;  margin-right:15px;  margin-bottom:10px; color:#5685bc; }
      .container2 p { margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px;  margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; line-height:1.3; font-size:small; }
      .container2 ul { margin-left:25px; font-size:small; line-height:1.4; list-style-type:disc; }
      .container2 li { padding-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px;}
    </style>
    <script src="js/jqueryv1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
      $ (document).ready(function() 
      {    
      <?php if (isset($_POST['create_form2'])): ?>
        $('#tabs li a:first').addClass('inactive');
        $('.container2').hide();
        $('.container2:last').show();
      <?php else: ?>      
            $('#tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
            $('.container2').hide();
            $('.container2:first').show();
       <?php endif ?>

      $('#tabs li a').click(function()
      {
        var t = $(this).attr('id');
        if($(this).hasClass('inactive'))
        { //this is the start of our condition 
          $('#tabs li a').addClass('inactive');         
          $(this).removeClass('inactive');
          $('.container2').hide();
          $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
        }
      });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
 <body>
    <ul id="tabs">
          <li><a id="tab1">FORM1</a></li>     
          <li><a id="tab2">FORM2 </a></li>        
    </ul>

    <div class="container2" id="tab1C">
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['create_form1']))
        {
           if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
              $errors[] = '<span class="error">All fields are required.</span>';
           }
           else {
              if (isset($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['username'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Username is required</span>'; }          
              if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && empty($_POST['firstname'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Firstname is required</span>'; }
           }
           if (empty($errors) === true) {
               $username = $_POST['username']; 
               $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
               echo $username.'lavanya<br>';
               echo $firstname.'<br>';              
           }
        }
      ?>
      <form method="post">
       <table>
        <tr><td><label>username</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"  size="30">             
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>firstname</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" >           
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit" style="background:#8AC007;color:#080808;padding:6px;" name="create_form1"></td></tr> 
       </table>
      </form>
      <?php          
        if (empty($errors) === false)            
        echo '<div>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</div>';             
      ?>     
    </div>

    <div class="container2" id="tab2C">
     <?php
        if (isset($_POST['create_form2']))
        {      
           $fullname = $_POST['fullname']; 
           $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 

           if (empty($_POST['fullname']) || empty($_POST['lastname'])) {
              $errors[] = '<span class="error">All fields are required.</span>';
           }
           else {
              if (isset($_POST['fullname']) && empty($_POST['fullname'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">fullname is required</span>'; }          
              if (isset($_POST['lastname']) && empty($_POST['lastname'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">lastname is required</span>'; }
           }
           if (empty($errors) === true)   {
              echo $fullname.'<br>';
              echo $lastname.'<br>';              
           }              
        }
      ?>
      <form method="post">
       <table>
        <tr><td><label>fullname</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["fullname"])) echo $fullname; ?>" size="30">               
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>lastname</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname" size="30" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["lastname"])) echo $lastname; ?>">              
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit" style="background:#8AC007;color:#080808;padding:6px;" name="create_form2"></td></tr> 
       </table>
      </form>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```